# using event load with feedBurner

Tags: jquery, load

I'm using google feedburner to show feeds on my website. The sript looks like this:

```
<div>
<script src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/nu/gbKB?format=sigpro" type="text/javascript" ></script></div>
```

As you can see I have placed it in a div. The problem is that I don't want to load the script on page load/document ready. I rather have the div loaded on a click of a button. So I tried Jquery event load. I placed the script on a blank document and saved as html page. I then placed this html page on my server and I tried calling it with jquery like this:

```
$('#button').click( function(event) {
$('div').load('feed.html');
});
```

This doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AJAX to get contents and if that contents are JS, you can execute that using `eval`.

Comment: because you must have server side script in file and call like `load('feed.php')`

Comment: If you call feed.html that will load script with including URL, not executing that.